# Writing JavaScript script inside C# code

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an asp.net application and i need to combine C# and javascript code:

```
<td >
    <label name="tag@(i)">@Model[1][i]._tag</label>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" value="@Model[1][i]._client" name="client@(i)"/>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" value="@Model[1][i]._reception"  class="datepicker" name="reception@(i)"/>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" value="@Model[1][i]._cloture"  class="datepicker" name="cloture@(i)"/>
</td>
<td>
    @{
        List<Planning.Models.Impaire> liste = u.Get_Impaire_List();
        Planning.Models.Impaire imp = liste.Find(x => x.id_paire == Model[1][i].Id);

        @{
            string reception =  @: <script>
            @: var f1 = $('input[name="reception' + @i.ToString() + '"]').val();
            @: document.write(f1);
            @: </script>
            ;
            string cloture =  @: <script>
            @: var f2 = $('input[name="cloture' + @i.ToString() + '"]').val();
            @: document.write(f2);
            @: </script>
            ;
            string client =  @: <script>
            @: var f3=  $('input[name="client' + @i.ToString() + '"]').val();
            @: document.write(f3);
            @: </script>
            ;
            string tag =  @: <script>
            @:var f4= $('input[name="tag' + @i.ToString() + '"]').val();
            @: document.write(f4);
            @: </script>
            ;
        }

        @Html.ActionLink("enregistrer","Index", new {identificateur = Model[1][i].Id, Pages = "1", _reception =reception, _cloture = cloture, _client = client, _tag = tag  })
    </td>
```

But I have an exception in this line : `@: var f1 = $('input[name="reception' + @i.ToString() + '"]').val();` [image: error]

What are the reasons of this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: did you have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having js inside the view like your sample is highly unlucky and can always be avoided. Find a way to separate javascript from razor code as good as you can. You could leave javascript variables inside the view alike

```
var arr = [@i.ToString()]
```

and then, in a *separate js file* you process this js variable arr.

Comment: i got the same result in adding `var arr = [@i.ToString()]`

Comment: the error message in the image is not readable, since it is 1. too small, 2nd in french, which I am not too good at. Looks like your template code is invalid. Maybe cut out parts until it works to find where it hangs.

Comment: `Compilation error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to meet this demand. Please see below the details of the error in question and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1002:; expected`

Comment: Well that is a syntax error in the template code. That should be easy to find, as said, cut out pieces of teplate code and you should find it.

Comment: but the same `shared` template didn't caused an mistakes in the other views. Why this one ?

Comment: `string reception =  
Ligne 811 :              
Ligne 812 :              #line default
Ligne 813 :              #line hidden
Ligne 814 :  item => new System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult(__razor_template_writer => {
Ligne 815 :  
Ligne 816 :  BeginContext(__razor_template_writer, "~/Views/Pages/Page1.cshtml", 5191, 11, true);
Ligne 817 :  
Ligne 818 :  WriteLiteralTo(__razor_template_writer, " <script>\r\n");
Ligne 819 :  
Ligne 820 :  EndContext(__razor_template_writer, "~/Views/Pages/Page1.cshtml", 5191, 11, true);
Ligne 821 :  
Ligne 822 :  })` the error is in the line 822